# Xcode Errors Creating Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have run into a lot of Xcode compiler issues while creating a Swift package from code I was trying to modularise and it has taken a fair bit of time trying to resolve without any success. Was hoping to get an idea on what could be the issue. So here it goes.

1. Created a Swift package named "MySPMPackage1" from Xcode menu.
2. Created a Swift file and added some code for UIImage Extension function. "Image+Extension.swift"

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SwiftImage

public extension UIImage {
    public func floatData() -> [Float32] {
        // Output
        var vals: [Float32] = []
        
        // Some business logic using swift image library
        let img = Image<RGBA<Float32>>(uiImage: self)
        return vals
    }
}
```

3. Extension function makes use of another swift package called [SwiftImage](https://github.com/koher/swift-image) which I have added into the Package.swift as follows.

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "MySPMPackage1",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MySPMPackage1",
            targets: ["MySPMPackage1"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/koher/swift-image.git", from: "0.7.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MySPMPackage1",
            /// 1. Gives Error
            /// No such module "SwiftImage"
            //            dependencies: []),

            /// 2. Gives Error
            /// product 'SwiftImage' required by package 'myspmpackage1' target 'MySPMPackage1' not found.
            dependencies: ["SwiftImage"]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "MySPMPackage1Tests",
        dependencies: ["MySPMPackage1"]),
]
)
```

4. Project does not compile. When the dependancies array under the "target" is left empty it gives "No such module "SwiftImage" for the extension class. If the array is contains "SwiftImage" it gives another error, mentioned below.
5. Main app in Xcode does not compile because package is failing. In addition, under schema, I now see 2 separate packages called "MySPMPackage1" and "MySPMPackage1-package". Even if I delete the latter, it keeps coming back after trying to build.

[image]

6. I have tried adding SwiftImage to main app target as a Swift package as well, but still the project does not compile. Also tried resetting package cache and updating and clearing derived data folder. Using Xcode 14.3 (14E222b)
7. There are no issues checking out the SwiftImage package. When I remove the Swift package and move the extension into main app everything works fine.

Have referred [Apple's own guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-standalone-swift-package-with-xcode) as well as some other resources [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/build-a-swift-package-in-5-minutes-21b346f2e537)
and [here](https://www.kodeco.com/7242045-swift-package-manager-for-ios)

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try in the dependencies array to include the package like this:             dependencies: [
                .product(name: "SwiftImage", package: "swift-image")
]